# How to create a Web Template programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, web-template

I want to create a Web Template programmatically in Sharepoint 2010.

I have read Vesa "vesku" Juvonen blog where he creates a web template using the elements.xml file and onet.xml file, but i want to do this programmatically.

Is this possible? Are there any blogs or code sample that show how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions themselves need to be done through xml with the elements and onet files.  Any other customization or feature activation can be done using feature receivers and code.

I've worked through some scenarios were I have minimal things defined in the xml, and then do much of the work in the feature receivers where you have full access to the api and code versus declarative means.